# Difference between bioinformatics and cheminformatics

Tags: genomics, cheminformatics

Anyone can answer, and should be in simple way

Comment: A reminder to not downvote newbies, but inform them why their Q is problematic. In this case it's a LMGTFY situation w/ no info of what may be the source of confusion and the body is not informative.

Answer (score 1):

There are four terms to consider, all are computational

- cheminformatics — [Big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) to explore relationship between small molecules (e.g. enumeration and machine learning stuff)
- computational chemistry ("compchem") - thermodynamics-based methods to explore small molecules (e.g. docking)
- bioinformatics — big data primarily for exploring -omics data (genomics, proteomics, transcriptomics, metabolomics)
- computational biochemistry - thermodynamics-based methods to study structure of protein