# general cheminformatics references

Tags: computational-biochemistry, cheminformatics

Can anyone explain what is cheminformatics and how does it help in the future?

I need to write an article that should be understandable for 14-20 yr age group. Please help with references, I don't know anything.

Comment: Hi Harsha, is this a homework of some sort? What's the context of figuring out what chemoinformatics is?

Comment: Hi, this is about writing an article on cheminformatics for people 14-20 yr age group should understand, I know some basics but can't figure what should I include like subheading and context

Answer (score 3):

- The definition of cheminformatics has been covered in [Difference between bioinformatics and cheminformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17810/difference-between-bioinformatics-and-cheminformatics/17811#17811)
- For a reference, simply citing [Essentials of Computational Chemistry by C. Cramer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essentials-Computational-Chemistry-Christopher-Cramer/dp/0470091827) will do it. I do not know if the newer Clayden (nitrile cover) deals with computational methods, but the old one (water+formaldehyde on cover) did not. In generally, a textbook is a very good way to get familiar with a field and Cramer's book is good.